# Adding login / register functionality to ruby rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been following the tutorial on: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and ive managed to complete the tut and have the blog app working. I wanted to take thinngs further and add login / register functionality to the app using: https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication

Thing is i dont get firstly how to install this properly... secondly how i would go about adding it onto my existing project.

Perhaps this is a lil too ahead of my learning curve right now, it's possible i should stick to simpler things but any help would be appreciated.

Regards
M

running rails 3.1.1
ruby 1.9.3p0

Answer (score 2):

If you're installing a new project with rails 3.1, go with devise (or authlogic) for authentication. Restful-authentication is a bit dated at this point.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 1):

that version of restful authentication is written for rails 2.3

The routes.rb file contains syntax like "map.resource" which has been replaced with "match" and "resource"

you can convert it, but you have to learn about what was changed in rails 3.

Here is another version of restful_authentication that will work with rails 3 out of the box.

https://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the Blog tutorial that you provided contains a link to a Ruby on Rails tutorial book. Here is the link to save you the trouble of having to look for it. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

Use better devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or authlogic (https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) for authentication. Both are simple to install and use.